# How to get the next row in mysqli result?

Tags: php, mysql, list, mysqli, associative-array

I want to get the next row in a cycle of a mysql result to write a list with the next and previous element code like this example:

```
<?php $previous = null;
$next = null;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$next = ??????????????? // how to get it?
?>
<li code="<?php echo $row['code']; ?>" previous="<?php echo $previous; ?>" next="<?php echo $next; ?>">Hello world!</li>
<?php
$previous = $row['code']; // previous is easy to get...
} ?>
```

Comment: I don't think you can "peek" at the next result.  Your best bet is to load all the results, then iterate it with a `for` loop.

Comment: You could store each row in an array and then loop through the array. Not ideal, but it would work

Comment: I wonder what should happen if there's no 'next' result. Where's no result at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at this solution, what do you think about it? it works, but will be more slow? this algorithm requires at least double pass or not? what do you think?

```
$db = DB::getConnection();
$result = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM objects" );

$next = null;
$previous = null;
$temp_previous = null;
$print = false;
$row = null;
$fetchit = false;
$code = null;
echo "<ul>";
while (true)
{

if ($print) {
   if ($fetchit) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $next = $row['code'];
   }
   echo "<li code='$code' next='$next' previous='$previous'>{$row['description']}</li>" . endl();
   $previous = $temp_previous;
   $print = false;
}
else {
 if (!$fetchit)
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 $code = $row['code'];
 $temp_previous = $row['code'];
 $print = true;
 $fetchit = true;
}

if(!is_array($row)) break;

}

echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: I think it's too much bloated and - to my humble opinion - quite useless.

Comment: the idea is to make a useless function for print html trees:
simply you call the function tree( $data ); and it will writes the html structure and the elements. The 'next' and 'previous' attributes is for easy to know where you are when you use javascript (jquery)

Comment: it ought to be separated into 2 parts: a function to get data and a function to print trees, a latter one totally independent from data source.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with MySQLi but here is how I do it in PDO:

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
   $next = isset($data[$i+1]) ? $data[$i+1] : null;
}
```

if there is no **fetchAll** in **mysqli** then do:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $data[] = $row;
}

if ( ! empty($data)) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
     $next = isset($data[$i+1]) ? $data[$i+1] : null; // next
     $prev = isset($data[$i-1]) ? $data[$i-1] : null; // previous
     $curr = isset($data[$i])   ? $data[$i]   : null; //current
  }
}
```

Comment: off the top of my head i don't believe this will work with mysqli, unfortunately

Comment: ah right, yeah, theres's no fetchall in mysqli. your second answer is the only out of the box way to do this that i know of. (mysqli blows)

Comment: There is a MySQLi version of `fetch all` :) https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 0):

How about something on the lines of this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > '$currentID' ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

to get the single next possible row.